# How to create markup with HTML 4.01 Transitional?

Tags: html, markup

I used the Structured Data Markup Helper from Google to create a markup for my webpage and filled the markup in my html. But when I then used the html validator from www.validator.w3.org I got a bunch of errors just from the markup I just added. Is it not possible to markup using HTML 4.01 Tranditional? Thanks!

Comment: HTML 4.01 Transitional was supposed to be an intermediate step for people converting from HTML 3.2 to 4.01 Strict, which came out in 1999. Why haven't you finished transitioning yet? (Or moved on to HTML 5 which supersedes 4.01 Strct) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the JSON-LD serialisation of the [data format](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?topic=3070267&hl=en-GB&rd=1) if you want it to be valid HTML 4.01 Transitional. The microdata format simply isn't valid.

Comment: Oh I misread the question - the OP is saying the markup is failing validation *after* being processed.